# Use nginx upstream group with multiple ports

Tags: nginx

I would like to use the same upstream definition with multiple ports:

```
upstream production {
    server 10.240.0.26;
    server 10.240.0.27;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some.host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production:1234;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name other.host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production:4321;
    }
}
```

Using that configuration `nginx -t` throws: `upstream "production" may not have port 1234` and returns with exitcode 1.

When I try to define the `proxy_pass` URL (or parts of) as a variable like:

```
set $upstream_url "http://production:1234"
set $upstream_host production;
set $upstream_port 1234;
proxy_pass $upstream_url;
# or
proxy_pass http://production:$upstream_port;
# or
proxy_pass http://$upstream:$upstream_port;
```

Nginx tries to resolve the name of my upstream via resolver:

```
 *16 no resolver defined to resolve production, client: ...., server: some.host, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "some.host"
```

For me, the [proxy_pass doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) sounds as if exactly that should not happen;

> A server name, its port and the passed URI can also be specified using
>   variables:
>
> proxy_pass http://$host$uri; or even like this:
>
> proxy_pass $request; In this case, the server name is searched among
>   the described server groups, and, if not found, is determined using a
>   resolver.

Tested with nginx versions:

- 1.6
- 1.9
- 1.10
- 1.11

Am I missing something? Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must define port in every `server` entry in `upstream`. If you don't nginx will set it to `80`. So `server 10.240.0.26;` actually means `server 10.240.0.26:80;`.

You could define several upstream blocks though:

```
upstream production_1234 {
    server 10.240.0.26:1234;
    server 10.240.0.27:1234;
}
upstream production_4321 {
    server 10.240.0.26:4321;
    server 10.240.0.27:4321;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some.host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production_1234;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name other.host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production_4321;
    }
}
```

Another option is to configure your local DNS to resolve hostname `production` to several IPs, and in this case nginx will use them all.

> http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass: If a domain name resolves to several addresses, all of them will be used in a round-robin fashion.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some.host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production:1234;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did knew about using multiple upstream blocks but as I need to auto generate those (dynamically changing list of hosts and lots of ports) I thought I could probably just use one. Accepting anyways as your answer is correct and very complete

Answer (score 5):

When you use upstreams, the ports are defined in the upstream blocks:

```
upstream production {
    server 10.240.0.26:8080;
    server 10.240.0.27:8081;
}
```

In other words, nginx resolves `proxy_pass` argument either to a upstream group or a `host:port` pair. When you use a variable as argument, it only resolves to `host:port` pair.